# Get all usernames in a database SYNCHRONOUSLY

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a root in the database like this:

```
users {
    "user1" {
          username: "username1",
          email: "email@email.com"
     }
    "user2" {
          ...
     }
     ...
}
```

Now, I want to register a new user, so for that I need to check if the username that the new user choose is already chosen.
For that I created a single time event and gather all usernames in a string list:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();

            Iterable<DataSnapshot> users = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            for (DataSnapshot user : users) {
                res.add(user.child("username").getValue(String.class));
            }
            // No way to return anything
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //handle databaseError
        }
    });
```

But I have a problem, that method is **asynchronous**. I need to gather all usernames and know if any exists in that list **synchronously**.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689663/firebase-multiple-users-simultaneously-updating-same-object-using-its-old-valu, https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

Comment: I don't see how it could help me, the problem is not with the data corruption, but is with that I need all that information on a single time.

Comment: OK, did some more "research" and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554623/firebase-how-to-prevent-duplicate-entries-atomically - accepted answer suggests setting the unique field as a key so that it won't be possible to insert duplicate